# Infinitive clauses and time adverbs - Last month, I agreed to help them **the next day/one day later/on 11/12**

Tags: infinitive-clauses, time-reference

In reported speeches, we have to change time references

How about an infinitive clause?

Let's assume right now is Dec 26 and last month, on Nov 11, I agreed to help on Nov 12.

**Example 1**

> Me: Last month, I agreed to help them **the next day/one day later/on Nov 12**.

Can I write Example 1 like that?

What if I agreed to help last month and the day I am going to help is tomorrow? Do I need to shift the time reference?

**Example 2**

> 1. Me: Last month, I agreed to help them with moving **tomorrow**.
> 2. Me: Last month, I agreed to help them with moving **the next month**.

Comment: It feels unnatural to say _the next day_ when you haven't specified the date of the agreement. Surely you would just say "Last month I agreed to help for a day" or "on Nov. 12" if it was a significant date.

Comment: So to-infinitive clauses require shifted time adverbs just like reported speeches? Do they follow the rules?

Comment: Surely this isn't specific to _English_ grammar? If you refer to _the next day_, you need to specify which day it was next to, not say vaguely 'last month'. _Tomorrow_ is always the day after today.

Comment: It is "reported speech", uncountable. speeches are what people give to groups of people.

Answer (score 1):

> Me: Last month, I agreed to help them **the next day/one day later/on Nov 12**.

All three options are correct. Perhaps "one day later" is a bit vague, as KB mentioned in a commment (one might wonder, one day later than what?), but it is certainly grammatically correct.

---

> What if I agreed to help last month and the day I am going to help is tomorrow? Do I need to shift the time reference?

I depends. Let's consider each of your exampes.

> Me: Last month, I agreed to help them with moving tomorrow.

We usually use "tomorrow" to refer to the day after today (the date on which the sentence is spoken or written), not the day after some other day that is mentioned. Therefore, this would mean that I agreed to help them with moving on December 27, not November 12.<sup>1</sup>

> Me: Last month, I agreed to help them with moving the next month.

In this case, "the next month" means the month after November (i.e., December). Referring to the month after December (i.e., January) requires only a small change to the adverbial phrase:

> Me: Last month, I agreed to help them with moving next month.

---

<sup>1</sup> Another answer notes that "tomorrow" might be ambiguous. That is true, but it usually means "the day after today", and that is how listeners or readers are likely to understand it here.

Answer (score 0):

The OP states in the question:

> In reported speeches, we have to change time references.

In some cases this is correct. consider:

> (1) Last month, John said that he would do the job **tomorrow**. [image: Red X, indicating incorrect or undesirable form]

If John spoke on November 12, but this statement is made on December 10th, did John promise to do the job on November 13th or on December 11th? So **ambiguous** relative time references should be changed, as in:

> (1A) Last month, John said that he would do the job **the next day**. [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]

Or made absolute, as in:

> (1B) Last month, John said that he would do the job **on 11 December, which is now tomorrow**. [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]

But time references which are not relative, or not ambiguous, need not be changed

> - (1C) Last month, John said that he would do the job **on the second Thursday in December**. [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]
> - (1D) Last month, John said that he would do the job **the next day**. [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]

So consider the examples in the question (renumbered here):

> - (2A) Last month, I agreed to help them **the next day**.  [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]
> - (2B) Last month, I agreed to help them **one day later**.   [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]
> - (2C) Last month, I agreed to help them **on Nov 27**.  [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]

All of these are acceptable. Sentence (2B) is slightly ambiguous, because "*one day later*" can mean "*the next day*" or "*on an [unspecified] later day*" but the 2nd of thee is quite unusual.

However, time references which are inherently ambiguous should be avoided, such as:

> - (2D) Last month, I agreed to help them **tomorrow** [image: Red X, indicating incorrect or undesirable form]
> - (2E) Last month, I agreed to help them **in two months** [image: Red X, indicating incorrect or undesirable form]

In both (2D) and (2E) it is unclear whether the time is relative to when the promise was made, or to when the current statement is being made. That ambiguity makes threes forms undesirable. This is not because an infinitive clause was used.  Consider:

> - (3A) Last month, I agreed that I would do the job **the next day**.  [image: Green check mark, indicating an acceptable form]
> - (3B) Last month, I agreed that I would do the job **tomorrow** [image: Red X, indicating incorrect or undesirable form]

Sentence (3A) is acceptable because it is clear, while (3B) is ambiguous. The principle is the same whether an infinitive clause is used or not.